# how can i open a text file from php using fileselector

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want to open a text file in php using file selector in html

this is my code for HTML

```
<form>
    <select>
        <option value="">Select a source</option>
        <option value="NOTEPAD">NOTEPAD</option>
        <option value="XML">XML</option>
        <br>
        <input type="file" name="datafile" id="fileid" size="40"> 
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Read Source" onclick="showRSS('test')"></input>
    </select>
</form>
```

i am trying to get path from `ID="fileid"` and sending it to php

```
var num;
num="xyz"; 
var loc;
var loc = document.getElementById("fileid").value;
xmlhttp.open("GET","read.phpq="+encodeURIComponent(num)+"&x="+encodeURIComponent(loc),true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

My php code is:

```
$lc=$_GET['x'];
$i=$_GET['q'];
$myfile = fopen($lc, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

but my file path shows as C:\fakepath\try.txt, 
how can i send the correct path to my php script.

Comment: You need to upload the file first, also by `read.phpq` I guess you wanted to type `read.php?q`

Answer (score 0):

Try temp_name in the server where it is being saved.

Answer (score 0):

U must have to upload file first to server.
if u want this thing at time of select file use  jquery file uploader instead of fileselector control. Because Jquery file uploader will directly upload file on server at given path.

Comment: i have uploaded the file to the server, how can i get rid of the file path like "C:\fakepath\dexter1.txt" , now i need only dexter1.txt.

Comment: If u upload ur file to server. Then u know very well where file is stored. Appned this path : For example: in  'temp' folder u stored file. $text_file = 'temp/dexter1.txt';

Comment: USE $_FILES["file"]["name"]  to get uploaded file name into php At time of upload.